# Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class:GAILogger

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xamarin

I have created an app in Xamarin iOS, I had created this with xcode 6.2 and OS was Marvick. But this app stared to crash in iOS 9, so I have upgraded application Xcode to version 7.0.1 and OS to OS X 10.11 El Capitan.
Now while building an app I am getting 2 errors as:
1st Error

Description:

> Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class:GAILogger. The
>   symbol 'OBJC_CLASS$_GAILogger' could not be found in any of the
>   libraries or framework linked with your application. (MT5211)

File:

> MTOUCH

2nd Error
Discription:

> Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class:GAILogger. The
>   symbol 'OBJC_CLASS$_GAITracker' could not be found in any of the
>   libraries or framework linked with your application. (MT5211)

File:

> MTOUCH

this is very critical issue and I am looking to release new update to app for iOS 9.
Any help to resolve this will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your linking behavior? Try Link Framework SDK-s only

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: Double click the project, Options>iOS Build> Linker behaviour and choose Link Framework SDKs Only

Comment: @BUKA, yes i check it, its already selected as Link Framework SDKs only

Comment: As it seems from the error, the problem is in linking. You are using the libraries which are not linked. Solution may be the changing the linking behavior to Don't link, but it may increase the app size.

Comment: Are you using Xamarin's provided Google Analytics, or including a custom version (and binding) of your own?

Comment: xamarin provided google analytics

Comment: Has this been solved?

Comment: yes, it was solved somehow by then, didn't had any idea which application update or any binding changes made it worked.